# Regular expression incorrect output by python

Tags: python, regex

```
import os,re
def test():
    list  = re.findall(r'(255\.){2}','255.255.252.255.255.12')
    print list
if __name__ == '__main__':
test()
```

the output ：“['255.', '255.']”

why not 【255.255，255.255】 ？

the mactch object should is "255.255"

How can i get  the correct output result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mm, not quite. First off, you'll want a non-capturing group - the capturing group you have there will only capture '255.', and use that as the output for `re.findall`.

Example:

```
re.findall(r'(?:255\.){2}', '255.255.252.255.255.12')
```

The (?:) construct is a non-capturing group - and without any capturing groups, re.findall returns the entire matching string.

Note that this won't actually return `['255.255', '255.255']` - it will actually return `['255.255.', '255.255.']`.

Answer (score 2):

In your regex, you're only capturing the first `255.`. You need to wrap everything you want to capture in a capturing group:

```
>>> re.findall(r'((?:255\.){2})','255.255.252.255.255.12')
['255.255.', '255.255.']
```

`(?:...)` is a non-capturing group. It basically lets you group things without having them show up as a captured group.